# Getting current location using Google map api

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift2

I'm trying to get current location of the user, however, the map gets stuck in UK. I edited info.plist for the permission. Here's my mapviewcontroller class and can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? Thanks

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class MapViewController: UIViewController {

    var newMap: Bool!
    let locationManager =  CLLocationManager()
    var didFindMyLocation = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    }


}

extension MapViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthroizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .AuthorizedAlways {

            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        }
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
         let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
         let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(locValue.latitude,
                                                      longitude: locValue.longitude, zoom: 6)
         let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)

         mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: locValue, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)

         mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
         mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true

         locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

}
```

EDIT : I'm testing it on simulator and set the simulation location to cities other than London.

Comment: Are you testing this on simulator ?

Comment: do you got a popup asking for permission ?

Comment: @Teja Nandamuri : Yes on simulator and I set the location under "simulation location" to cities other than London.

Comment: @Mohamed Mostafa : Yup, it did ask for permission, but only once. Any subsequent running doesn't ask permission anymore.

Comment: try to call locationManager.startUpdatingLocation() in viewDidLoad and remove locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong in my code. It is because I forgot to enable the Google Place API!